# Excel VBA code error: Method or data member not found

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

While executing the attached pic.
In the code in the Excel VBA editor I see a dialogue box displaying

> Compile Error: Method or data membor not found

The code which is highlighted with yellow color is:

```
Private Sub cmdAddData_Click()
```

Comment: Something's missing from your question...

Comment: There's no way to tell what the problem is without *all* of the code. Please [edit] your question to include it.